# Cat coughing, we are not sure what it is

Tags: cats

Our cat (Ragdoll) has this coughing from time to time, not really sure what it is. Nothing really changes in the environment. He does have some heart condition, enlarged heart. He takes pills: Xarelto and Enaladex.
Video: https://streamable.com/yiyfx2
We are waiting for a response from his vet but any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

This is not something that can be diagnosed over the internet, so your cat does need to see a vet as soon as possible. As long as he is not in respiratory distress (difficulty breathing) and is otherwise well, he is likely fine to wait until you hear back from your vet. If you notice any indication of respiratory distress then he should be seen by an emergency veterinarian immediately.

Coughing can occur for many reasons, including infections, bronchitis or asthma, cancer, heart disease, and other causes.

With the history of heart disease (presumably hypertrophic cardiomyopathy based on your description and his breed), the immediate concern is this could be heart-related. Coughing is a fairly uncommon cause of heart disease except in the more advanced stages, as if a cough develops due to heart disease it is often an indication of congestive heart failure. This is usually a result of pulmonary edema and/or pleural effusion — fluid buildup in or around the lungs. If this is the case, fluid may need to be drained, or diuretic medications started.

X-rays of your cat's chest are likely the next step your vet will need to take to diagnose the problem.

Please give us an update once your cat has been to the vet.

Comment: Thank you Harry, much appreciated. I will update once we have more instruction from our vet.

Comment: @Captain_Meow_Meow this forum cannot and will not replace an opinion from a veterinary professional.